# How to check the Security of system?

Tags: security, antivirus

Is there any antivirus or any sort of scanner available for Linux so that one can insure the security of system and is it so that Ubuntu is hack-proof?

If not than what are the basic steps which a new Ubuntu user keep in mind for security concern.

Comment: *Nothing* is hack proof. what are you specifically afraid  of? Ubuntu is secure as it is, given that you don't go around fiddling with unknown software. Also look at the questions under **Related** ---->

Comment: It is safe to assume your system is virus free. Really.

Comment: Also refer [Ubuntu's Basic Security guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BasicSecurity) , plus [**this**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BasicSecurity/DidIJustGetOwned) seems to Answer your question

Comment: clamav, chkrootkit, rkhunter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup a Virtual Machine using Virtualbox or VMWare and install [Backtrack](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/downloads/). Once Backtrack is setup and installed, configure [Nessus](https://securityweekly.com/2011/05/11/activating-nessus-on-backtrack/). Once Nessus is installed access it via a browser and scan the Ubuntu system. Nessus will provide a report on any security vulnerabilities it finds. Keep in mind it won't find everything. I would also recommend consulting the [CIS benchmarks](http://benchmarks.cisecurity.org/downloads/benchmarks/) for further securing your Ubuntu instances.